# Убрать мусор из урла через .htaccess

Tags: url, .htaccess

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Нужно, чтобы из урла http://domain.ru/ru/?option=com_models_filter&view=filters&hash=c712944ecc4c70c354105d76c5718441

пропадал весь вот этот мусор "?option=com_models_filter&view=filters&hash=" и оставался более чистый домен в виде  http://domain.ru/ru/c712944ecc4c70c354105d76c5718441

Ссылки динамичные, но часть "?option=com_models_filter&view=filters&hash=" всегда одинаковая.

Надеюсь, я правильно выразился. =)

СПАСИБО!

В хтакессе совсем чайник=( Буду очень благодарен рабочему решению =(...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить это в файл .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)option=com_models_filter&view=filters&hash=(.*)$ $1/$2
```

За правильность не ручаюсь, но копать вам надо в сторону `mod_rewrite`. Поищите, думаю, есть готовые решения.

**Обновление**

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)hash=(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) /ru/%2 [R]
```

Данное правило разобьет запрос - до hash и после него. Если после hash ничего больше нет, то работать будет корректно, в противном случае меняйте условие  RewriteCond, чтобы ограничивалось символом &.

Comment: Просидел вчера 5 часов, так и не смог решить. Спасибо, за подсказку. В общем, догадываюсь, что через реврайт, но, увы, не выходит. В хтакессе совсем чайник. =(

Comment: Попробуйте так:

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)hash=(.+)$
    RewriteRule (.*) /ru/%2 [R]
 
Данное правило разобьет запрос - до hash и после него. Если после hash ничего больше нет, то работать будет корректно, в противном случае меняйте условие  RewriteCond, чтобы ограничивалось символом &.